# Password stored in google chrome's browser memory

Tags: javascript, security, chromium

When I login and logout from my application, my username and password are stored into chrome browser memory. When I create a dump file from the task manager for that particular process Id and open that file in WinHex tool and search for username or password field I'm able to see my password in clear text and now I want to encrypt or clear that password field.

```js
function onLogin(btnName) {
    var parameters = getFormValues();

    //if (!validateParameter(parameters.userName, parameters.password))
    //    return;

    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader(parameters.antiForgeryTokenName, parameters.antiForgeryToken);
        }
    });
    var getSecuritySettingsUrl = getVirtualDirectoryUpdatedURL("/login/GetSecuritySettings");
    $.ajax({
        url: getSecuritySettingsUrl,
        type: "GET",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (result) {
            try {
                var response;
                if (result.IsHashed) {
                    var decryptedData = decryptWithDefaultSetting(result.viewData);
                    if (decryptedData.isError) {
                        alert(decryptedData.result);
                        return;
                    }
                    response = JSON.parse(decryptedData.result);
                }
                else {
                    response = JSON.parse(result.viewData);
                }

                if (response.IsPasswordHashed) {
                    if (isNullOrUndefined(response.SaltText)) {
                        throw new Error("Please refresh the page and try again");
                    }
                    encriptPass = encryptByInputKey(parameters.form["Password"].value, response.SaltText).result;
                }
                $('#btnType').val(btnName);
                $('form input[name="Password"]').val(encriptPass);
                $('#loginForm').submit();
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
                if (!isNullOrUndefined(error)) {
                    if (!isNullOrUndefined(error.message)) {
                        alert(error.message);
                    }
                    else if (!isNullOrUndefined(error.Message)) {
                        alert(error.Message);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Some error has occurred. Please refresh the page and try again");
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
            console.log(xhr);
            alert("Please refresh the page and try again : " + xhr.statusText);
        }
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the threat you are protecting this against? If an attacker already has privileges to access the browser's memory, you are kind of losing anyway.

Comment: If in any case an attacker gets the access of browser's memory and he tries to find the password the value should be encrypted or blank. So, the users password will not be compromised.

Comment: My question was, in what scenario would that happen, how would an attacker be able to access a user's browser memory to such extent that he can extract a password? What is the attack vector? My point is, if there is such access, the attacker will likely have full control over the client anyway.

Comment: @RohitJain were you able to fix this issue, bro?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem earlier by salting and hashing the user entered password in the UI and passing both the salted value and hash to server for authentication. The same salt has to be applied during the server side password validation.

Comment: I have also did the same thing but issue still persist, can you provide the code.

Comment: I cannot share the code but the similiar solution is discussed here: https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/browser-based-vulnerabilities-in-web-applications/#gref